# Where do my email bounces go to?

Tags: email-bounces

I'm bit confused, I have a cron job that sends out 12 000 + emails every sunday night, now I'm not sure where the emails that are bounce get send to, will this always be the reply address specified in the email being send from? Centos is the Linux distro I use to send out mails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer would depend on your mail transfer agent set up and possibly how the emails are being sent.  If it is simply the "mail" or "mailx" command on Linux, then the email is most likely sent as "user@machinename.yourdomain.com", where user is the user who cron is being run, and machinename is the server you are running this under.  Keep in mind that the From: address in the mail body is merely the inside of the envelope.  There is also a sender address on the outside of the envelope, which many mail servers will use rather than the internal header (probably an RFP for that, but I have not looked it up).  If there is no way to deliver bounces to the sender account, it could be bouncing back to the postmaster at some
mail server along the way.

Answer (score 0):

The definitive way to find out is to run a packet capture when this cronjob is triggered, and examine the captured emails in a program like wireshark. This will let you examine the headers and see where bouncebacks would be returned, if anywhere.

Comment: Or just send one of the e-mails to an address where you can read it